# Validation password in c programming

Tags: c, regex, validation

i want to validate password in c programming with below rules.

- at least one uppercase word
- at least one lowercase word
- at least one number
- at least one symbol (!@#$%^&*)
- length: 8 - 32

how can I do that with regex or without it?

Comment: So what have you tried? Got some code for us to look at?

Comment: You might have a loop and use macros like [isalpha(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html); is the input UTF-8?

Comment: I tried (regcomp(&re,"^(?=(.*\d))(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).{8,32}$", REG_EXTENDED) != 0) but it generates error code 1.

Comment: As an aside, I think rules like this are annoying. They force people to invent hard-to-remember passwords or doing simple substitution of letters with similar digits / symbols, which hardly adds any security. The only rule I can fully agree with here is the lower length limit. Meanwhile, the upper limit of 32 characters could limit some people who want to use passphrases or [xkcd-style passwords](http://xkcd.com/936/) - what's the reason for that one?

Comment: This is an important password, not a regular password for a user. So I need a secure password.

Comment: @Medo42 +1 For the XKCD reference. Definitely the way forward! :-)

Comment: My point is that these rules don't do much to enforce the security of the password. Your rules would accept "P4$sw0rd" but reject "a4nGL5eqHBjecY2U2Bai" or "twenty fear express importance" which are both much safer, and the latter has the advantage of being much easier to remember, too.

Comment: If it is a duplicate question, please show me the answer!

Comment: It is linked at the top of your question. The part that says "This question already has an answer here:" in bold letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to satisfy all of your requirements,

```
^(?=.{8,32}$)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[(!@#$%^&*)]).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iX8hF3/7)

```
^(?=.{8,32}$)         -      length: 8 - 32
(?=.*?[A-Z])          -      at-least one uppercase letter.
(?=.*?[a-z])          -      at-least one lowercase letter.
(?=.*?[0-9])          -      at-least one number.
(?=.*?[(!@#$%^&*)])   -      at-least one symbol present inside the character class.
.*                    -      Match any character zero or more times only if all the above 5 conditions are true.
```

Comment: ret = regcomp(&re,"^(?=.{8,32}$)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[(!@#$%^&*)]).*", REG_EXTENDED) , it generates error code 1

Comment: problem is with your code only not in th regex. See the Demo site..

Comment: see here http://regex101.com/r/iX8hF3/8 . Your regex fails to match the second line..